# Boxed value unboxed then reboxed

Tags: java, findbugs, boxing, unboxing

FindBugs is giving me a warning about the following line, where `invoiceNumber` is an `Integer` object:

```
text.append(String.format("%010d-", (invoiceNumber == null) ? 0 : invoiceNumber));
```

The warning is: "Boxed value is unboxed and then immediately reboxed"

Now I think I understand (un)boxing, but I can't see how you would do the same thing without getting the warning?

I have found that I can get rid of the warning using the following code instead, but this seems more long-winded:

```
int invNo = (invoiceNumber == null) ? 0 : invoiceNumber;
text.append(String.format("%010d-", invNo));
```

Can someone show me what is the 'correct' way to do the above?

BTW, I've looked at the related questions and I understand what was going on with them, but this doesn't seem to match any of those.

Comment: Perhaps `text.append(String.format("%010d-", (invoiceNumber == null) ? Ineger.valueOf(0) : invoiceNumber));` will do.

Comment: Yes, that does get rid of the warning, but why is that 'better'. It's constructing an Integer object (which should be expensive), but it shouldn't need to.

Comment: In the case of 0 (or any integer from -128 to 127), it's not constructing any new Integer instance, since the instance is already available in the IntegerCache. And you are saving the unboxing and boxing operations, so it might give you a slight performance improvement.

Comment: Actually you do construct a new `Integer` in your original code as well as in your fix with `int invNo = (invoiceNumber == null) ? 0 : invoiceNumber;` (though FindBugs warning disappears), but using @Eran solution you will not construct the new Integer, but reuse the existing one. Well though Eran answer is correct (upvoted) in general you may just ignore this warning. It's very unlikely that it will actually harm the performance of your application. The created extra `Integer` is very short-lived.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The type of the `(invoiceNumber == null) ? 0 : invoiceNumber)` expression is 
`int`. It requires unboxing of `invoiceNumber` in the case `invoiceNumber` is not `null`.

On the other hand, `String.format` expects a single `String` argument followed by `Object` references, which means your `int` get immediately boxed to `Integer` again.

You can try to avoid the original unboxing by using `(invoiceNumber == null) ? Integer.valueOf(0) : invoiceNumber)`, which would make this expression return an `Integer`.

Comment: So does that mean that my 2 line 'solution' in my question is actually less efficient, because the `invoiceNumber` is unboxed to `invNo`, and then reboxed to an `Integer` for the `String.format`?

Comment: @DuncanKinnear, exactly!

Comment: @DuncanKinnear I'm assuming that your two line 'solution' only prevents FindBugs from detecting the unboxing and reboxing, so it doesn't actually change anything compared to your original code.

Comment: @DuncanKinnear No, the second version has the same inefficiency (save the assignment to a one-time-use local variable which the compiler probably optimizes away).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `(invoiceNumber == null) ? 0 : invoiceNumber` to `(invoiceNumber == null) ? 0 : invoiceNumber.intValue()`. I think the warning comes from you using the `Integer` again in the "false" case, not an `int`.

Comment: Nope, same warning. I tried casting the false value to `(int)` and I still got the warning.

Comment: The warning when away for me…what version of Java are you using?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the exact same code, including the `String.format`?

Comment: Yes. What is the type of `text`? A `StringBuilder`? `StringBuffer`?

Comment: `StringBuilder`. Probably not worth pursuing as Eran's solution seems a better fit. His explanation would also explain why the `intValue()` doesn't fix the 'problem' as the resulting `int` is still being boxed for use as the `String.format` argument.